# How to catch create db signal from django

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I'm working in django project. I have 1 postgresql sql file that need to run only one time after db created. Built-in django signal not quite suit with my case. So I try to write custom django signal but I'm not sure how to start with this case. Does anyone has a good guide. ? :)

Comment: Does the initial SQL data hook not work for you?

Comment: I'm not sure about this approach. But I need it run only one time. Will It work as I expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Django docs on signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/signals/) have improved dramatically, so take a look there if you haven't already. The process is pretty simple.

First create your signal (`providing_args` lets you specify the arguments that will get passed when you send your signal later):

```
import django.dispatch
my_signal = django.dispatch.Signal(providing_args=["first_arg", "second_arg"])
```

Second, create a receiver function:

```
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(my_signal)
def my_callback(sender, first_arg, second_arg, **kwargs):
    # do something
```

Finally, send your signal wherever you like in your code (`self` as sender is only applicable within your model class. Otherwise, just pass a the model class name):

```
my_signal.send(sender=self, first_arg='foo', second_arg='bar')
```

Comment: Since he has a one-time usage case, you should also point him to documentation on creating a Command so he can generate the signal on demand.